# Ternary operator condition

Tags: javascript, reduce, ternary

The following code uses the reduce method. It outputs the number of times an element appears in the array. If element appears once then it only outputs 1, otherwise if it is a repeated item then it it is added..

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"]

const t = a.reduce((aa, ll) => {
  const count = aa[ll];
  count
    ?
    aa[ll] = count + 1 :
    aa[ll] = 1
  return aa
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(t))

// output 
// { "a":2, "b":2, "c":1 }
```

Question is regarding the condition in  the ternary operation, specifically the **count** variable. How is the **count** variable able to resolve true or false.

Comment: That's a complete misuse of the conditional operator IMO. Use it when you need a conditional *expression*, not a substitute for `if`/`else`. The proper way to use it here would be `aa[ll] = count ? count + 1 : 1`

Comment: the standard assignment is `aa[ll] = (aa[ll] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: Any non-zero number is considered truthy, zero is falsey.

Comment: Also, `undefined` is falsey. So if the object property doesn't exist, it's false.

Comment: They exploit that `count` is `undefined` when `ll` doesn't exist in the object, and that `undefined` coerces to `false` in a condition. Better would've been an explicit check for existence of the property, e.g. `aa[ll] = ll in aa ? aa[ll] + 1 : 1`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Make that a `??` :-)

Comment: @Bergi, yes, i was tempted to write it this way, but it is takeing a numerical value an logical or is better and better known interms of compatibility.

Comment: IThank you for all the feedback. Unfortunately I didnt get the answer I was looking for.  the qustion wasnt about truthy or falsy or even rewriting the whole function.

Comment: @Gambit901 I quote from your question: *"How is the **count** variable able to resolve true or false."* That's exactly about "truthy" or "falsy" ...  It may not have been what you meant to ask, but it's what you actually did ask.

Comment: ok ill keep in mind to be careful on my verbiage when posting questions.  Ive been reading through stackover flow over the years.. But Ive never really signed up and asked questions, until now. thank you

Comment: @Gambit901 You could try rephrase your question. Maybe then you'll get the answer you are looking for ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called ["Truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and ["Falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) respectively. Ie anything that is different from `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined` and `""` (empty string) can be evaluated to `true` in Javascript

So your assign `var counter = aa[ll]` to be the value of the key `ll` in object `aa`.  That's either a number or `undefined`. If it's a number `!== 0` it's a truthy, if it's `0` or `undefined` it's falsy. Thus it can be used in a ternary operatator. Depending on the value of `counter` either the value of the first or the second assignment will be returned (but ignored). The return value of an assignment is always the value of the right hand side ...

While you can use also assignments in the expressions of a ternary operator, I personally wouldn't use it that way but write this assignment as follows

```
const t = a.reduce((aa, ll) => {
  aa[ll] = (aa[ll] || 0) + 1;
  return aa
}, {})
```

`(aa[ll] || 0)` will return the value of `aa[ll]` if it's a truthy or `0` otherwise. Thus, in your case, the result of this expression will always be a number `>= 0`. Then you increase the result by 1 (for the currenct occurence of `ll`) and assign it back to `aa[ll]`. This is much shorter than your original code and IMHO much more readable

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer I found.

"A javascript object consists of key-value pairs where keys are unique. If you try to add a duplicate key with a different value, then the older value for that key is overwritten by the new value."

basically the count variable was checking to see if the new property already exists.

Comment: Yes, but you can achieve that much easier by `aa[ll] = (aa[ll] || 0) +1`

Comment: can you provide this an the answer.  thank you